# How to share large files using WIFI between two Android Devices (like ShareIT & Zapya)

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, file-sharing, wifip2p

Can someone please guide me how i can **send/share** **large files** (movies, videos, images etc) between two **Android Devices** with the help of **WIFI**.

Just like the working of **ShareIt and zapya** etc. Is there any **library/API** with which I can **share files** (large/small) or **any other better way** so that I can make an App that will share small/large files.

**Thanks**

Comment: [WiFi direct](https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo)

Comment: Well, I have not started implementation so far as I'm first studying the concepts to achieve it like sharing with NFC, Bluetooth and WIFI and I feel wifi suitable due to large range and speed of sharing also good. So, what you suggest and is there any library/API that provide this feature or I should start it with scratch. @MohammedFarhan

Comment: Yeah, WIFI direct is really a nice concept about my choice and scenario. I'm  studying it. Thanks @sanemars :)

Comment: NFC has very poor throughput so I wouldn't recommend this for large files. In fact WiFi Direct has the best range and speed but it consumes far more energy than Bluetooth (Bluetooth EDR or HS). Depending on your use case you should also consider power consumption. You should check both technologies specs.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JakubLicznerski for your response. I'll surely think on it and really appreciate your response.